# How to set Local Currency Preference in AWS Billing Dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

Has the **Local Currency Preference** option been deprecated from AWS console?
My Billing Dashboard shows the cost in **USD**, I wanted to change this to my local currency **INR**.

[image]

When I searched I found this post - [Set Preferred Payment Currency for your AWS Account](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-set-preferred-payment-currency-for-your-aws-account/), but this seems to be a couple of years old so the options mentioned in the post are not found in the console. Is there any alternate way to change the currency in Billing Dashboard?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INR does not seem to be a supported currency for AWS Billing:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/supported-aws-currencies/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-set-preferred-payment-currency-for-your-aws-account/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my invoice is generating in INR, but in Dashboard it is showing as USD.

Comment: That's correct, it's not a supported currency as I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like INR is not yet supported by AWS for billing Dashboard.
However, you still get your billed amount invoice in INR. Setting for this is in -
Billing > Payment Preferences > edit Payment Preferences

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already had this setting in place but it didn't change the currency in Dashboard, its still in USD.